# La url amigable de mi web no funciona

Tags: html, url

Estoy programando en una web que trata de añadir noticias y quisiera transformar la URL resultante que tengo de noticias que voy agregando a **URL amigable** (SEF).

La URL que tengo es del tipo:

```html
  <a href="news-details.php?nid=<?php echo htmlentities($row['pid'])?>" class="btn btn-primary">Leer Mas &rarr;</a>
```

Y el codigo que tengo para que aparezca en URL amigable es

```html
<!--SEF-->
<a href="<?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($row['pid'])) . "%2D%2D" . rawurlencode(stripslashes($row['posttitle'])) . ".html";?>"
 <?php echo html_entity_decode('&gt;'); ?>
 <h3><?php echo htmlentities(stripslashes($entry_title)) . html_entity_decode('&lt;&#47;a&gt;'); ?>
 </h3></a>
 <!--Fin SEF-->
```

Y no funciona. Tengo que añadir adicionalmente algun codigo al archivo htaccess ??

Comment: Simplificando, lo que deseo es desde la URL NO amigable: https://miweb.com/blog/news-details.php?nid=12 que sea...https://miweb.com/blog/titulo-noticia

Comment: Alguna sugerencia en el htaccess ?